# datetimepicker opening up and not showing day month selection

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

I have used lightning-input type="date", however when it opens, it open up when it is zoomed and then hides the rest of the selection and doesn't work properly. Can you please suggest how to make it open at the bottom always. Here is a screenshot -

[image: Datetimepicker opening up]

Answer (score 0):

it is working "properly" the popover header is just hidden bellow the other element, this is an SLDS issue, the z-index seems to be inferior  than the other element. nothing you can do unfortunately. a workaround could be extending the containers height so top and bottom elements do not overlap